# Help with creating a view and updating an entity model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

EDIT: This question is vague and will likely be of little use to anyone.  I am awarding internet monies to the gentleman below whom "helped" me.

Sorry that the title is a little vague.  I am still new to asp mvc & EF.  Here is my issue.  I have a DB somewhat like this.

```
Employee
 - ID
 - Name
 - Address

EmployeeJob
 - EmployeeID
 - JobID
 - StartDate

JobTypes
  - ID
  - JobName
```

I want a create form that will show all the Employee fields as well as a list of JobTypes for the users to be able to select.  Then I will post the results back to the controller and update the DB.  I have started looking into custom viewmodels, but am still unsure of exactly how to put that together and get it to work.  Thanks,

Comment: What have you already tried?  Are you asking from a completely blank slate and you've haven't even read a single MVC tutorial yet?

Comment: I have completed the music store tutorial and looked at nerddinner.  But that is about the extent of my experience.  My problem is a little more complicated than this example, but for some reason I can't seem to get this basic step on my own.

Comment: I started by creating a viewmodel with Employee and a list of JobTypes.  Then in the controller i new'd up an employee and .ToList()'d the job types.  The view i made was strongly typed to the new custom vm.  Assuming the previous steps are valid I am stuck in the view and not sure how to build out the form correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a specific view model that reflects the data needed by the view to display the interface.  In this case, the employee information plus the collection of jobs represented by the current relations.  Add to that the information required to show the jobs menu -- in this case I'd use an enumeration of SelectListItems (Value = ID, Text = JobName).

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> CurrentJobs { get; set; }
    public int JobType { get; set; } // placeholder for post back value from menu
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on what you are trying to do you might want a different model for the post.

```
public class EmployeeJobAddition
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public int JobType { get; set; }
}
```

or (this might argue for a different collection for JobTypes in the view model)

```
public class EmployeeJobChange
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> CurrentJobTypes { get; set; }  // returns values to keep
    public IEnumerable<int> JobTypes { get; set; } // new jobs to add
}
```

Set up your form with input names to reflect the model being posted back, using the data supplied by the view model.

Comment: How do you setup the labels so that they match the model correctly?  So far i have just been using the @html.editfor helper.  I tried using that for the viewmodel but it didnt work.  Thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: @Dubyaohohdee - with a more complex model you might need to build the edit/display views yourself or use the other helpers directly, @Html.DropdownFor( m => m.JobType, Model.JobTypes ) -- note that the view model would need both JobType and JobTypes properties for this particular one.  You shouldn't view my examples as exact representations of your needs but prototypes to display how to make it work.

Comment: How do you populate JobTypes from your EmployeeViewModel in the controller?  And then how do you get it to display in the view?  I looked around online and couldnt get it to work.  I ended up using a list in the VM and manually building the select.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Dub - typically something like:  `JobTypes = db.JobTypes.Select( j => new SelectListItem { Text = j.JobName, Value = j.ID.ToString() } ).ToList();`  Since it's only used for building the select, I typically don't pass it back except as the selected item in the `JobType` property (i.e., the list must get repopulated on errors, redisplay).  I often have a helper method that takes a partial model and simply populates the select list if I use it in more than one place.

Comment: Thanks for your help. A++ Would ask questions to this person again.